# SetInterval running infinitely

Tags: react-native

```
         let pathValid;
         let item;
         console.log("getting in")
           const interval = setInterval(() => {
                    fire.database().ref().child(getpath())
                        .once("value",
                    (snapshot)=>{
                        let item=snapshot.val()
                        if(item!==null){
                        let array=[];
                        Object.
                        keys(item)
                        .forEach(i=>array.push(item[i]));

                   }

                   console.log(item,"item")
                   if(item!==null)
                   {   
                     console.log("gotout")
                     setStuff(item)   
                     clearInterval(interval);

                   }
                  })
                }, 1000)    
           }
```

I want the code to return item and stop  but the code is running infinitely.
Expected clearInterval to exit the code but doesn't seem to be working.
I am new to setInterval and react in general so please give explaination to the error

Comment: How do you use this code, and `isValid` function in particular?

Comment: This line of code does nothing: `clearInterval();`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @raina77ow isValid is used to find valid path from the db and when a valid path is found it should stop and return the item on that path.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Good catch, clearInterval without an argument is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems in the code. There may be other issues, but these jumped out at me.

First, this line does nothing:

```
clearInterval();
```

You have to pass your `interval` variable into the function as your other call below does.

Second, this is *asynchronous* code, so this line also does nothing useful:

```
return item
```

Presumably you want to get this `item` value into some other part of your code. But you can't do that by returning the value from your asynchronous function. The return value will be discarded.

Instead of the `return` statement, if you have another function that will use this value, you need to *call* that function and pass it `item` as a parameter.

Comment: The changes look good, but now I notice another problem that I didn't spot before. When you make the database call, isn't that also an asynchronous call? That innermost callback (where you have `let item = snapshot.val()` is probably where you need to be calling `setStuff(item)`. Also the `let pathValid;` and `let item;` at the very top of the code should be deleted.